# How to create drop down menu

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to create dropdown menu, this drop down menu is about name of countries, so when the user for example choose country A then all the posts that are associated with country A will be displayed.

So my question is do i need to create a separate PHP file for every country in order to get the posts that are associated to a particular country?

Comment: No you would just pass the country name or id to a single script, get the data and display it.

Comment: You are trying to do auto-complete field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you would create your dropdown as usual with

```
<select name="myCountry">
     <option>Country A</option>
     <option>Country B</option>
     <option>etc lol</option>
</select>
```

Then have your form point to your PHP processing file, and in there you would do something like.

```
$selectedCounty = $_GET['myCountry']; //This assigns the selected value from that country dropdown into a usable variable.
```

Then u query the database. 
*Lets assume you have a database table called "countries" and a column with the countries listed called "myCountries".*

```
$selectCountryQS = SELECT * FROM countries WHERE myCountries = '$selectedCountry';
```

Then put it into action

```
$selectCountryDoIt = mysqli_query('connection variable here', $selectCountryQS ) or die('error mssg'. mysqli_error(conection var here));
```

Then set a while loop that will grab ALL the posts data that you wanted.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectCountryDoIt)){
  echo $row[' your column data to display here'];
}
```

This will give you what you need.
Hope this helps. Good luck

Comment: for sure glad it worked for you. Welcome to SO =)